# Migration issue VS 2010 to VS 2015, missing symbol files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting some file not found errors. I simply moved the entire working solution to a new computer with VS 2015 Express. I get errors like missing `Bitmap.cs` and others - path not found. The Reference list is the same. Is there a missing setting or something else causing these errors.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284861/not-all-assemblies-are-being-loaded-into-appdomain-from-the-bin-folder), but I don't know how to fix this from that answer.

This happens only during debug, what does that mean?

Thanks.

Comment: You telling us your getting "strange errors" isn't specific enough to help us

Answer (score 1):

Some of VS errors are pretty ambiguous as to the real problem at hand. It seems during debug it was lost on getting the symbol files. The answer was to change the build configuration from `(Active x86)` to just `x86` on the active solution platform. After changing this the `(Active x86)` is gone - poss bug. Hope this may help others.